WiX Toolset 5 - Web API Installer - Files from publish folder
I am in the process of building a WiX Toolset 5 installer for a .NET 8 Web API project. I am familiar with older versions of WiX.
The problem I have is that when I do a dotnet publish this creates additional required files (most notably the web.config) that are NOT created with a dotnet build
In my WiX project how can I reference the publish directory of a the Web API project? Previously I would always TargetDir variable, but this is the build output and therefore I get a  missing file error.
<Component>
    <File Source="$(var.MyWebApiProject.TargetDir)web.config" />
</Component>

I want to avoid hard-coding any directories as this will need to run in a DevOps Pipeline also. Ideally I also want to avoid any manual copying too.

Add Publish='true' to the ProjectReference item in your .wixproj and the WiX build will publish and reference the target project. Note this publishes to a known location (in the .msi project) so pre-processor variables can be set.
You can then simply remove the variable from the file source.
<Component>
    <File Source="web.config" />
</Component>


I have added this <ProjectReference Include="..\MyApi\MyApi.csproj" Publish="true" /> but running a dotnet build -c Release and running via Visual Studio don't appear to create a publish folder?

Ah, I think I may have mis-understood, adding that publish, outputs the reference publish inside the .msi project output, is this correct? In which case, what do I modify my File Source too?

Yes, it has to publish them to a known location so it can set the preprocessor variables correctly. Look at a build log file to see the preprocessor variables and bind paths being set for you automatically.
